# Connection Refused Error installing Nextcloud on Synology NAS

Tags: mariadb, synology, nextcloud

Trying to install Nextcloud on a Synology NAS following [this guide](https://mariushosting.com/how-to-install-nextcloud-on-your-synology-nas/).

I am stuck on step 9. When I hit "Finish Setup" I get the following error:

> Error while trying to create admin user: Failed to connect to the database: An exception occurred in driver: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused

MariaDB is running on port 3307 and I am using 127.0.0.1:3307 in the Database Host field.

I have set the root password for MariaDB and validated that it works with phpMyAdmin.

The Apache log shows me this (not sure if it's related):

```
2020-02-07T09:06:52+01:00 Synology [Fri Feb 07 09:06:52.842797 2020] [core:alert] [pid 32462:tid 140624225343232] [client 192.168.1.50:34372] /var/services/web/nextcloud/data/.htaccess: Expected </IifModule> but saw </IfModule>
2020-02-07T09:07:06+01:00 Synology [Fri Feb 07 09:07:06.128359 2020] [core:alert] [pid 32462:tid 140624191772416] [client 192.168.1.50:34378] /var/services/web/nextcloud/data/.htaccess: Expected </IifModule> but saw </IfModule>
2020-02-07T09:07:20+01:00 Synology [Fri Feb 07 09:07:20.905597 2020] [core:alert] [pid 32462:tid 140624015525632] [client 192.168.1.50:34383] /var/services/web/nextcloud/data/.htaccess: Expected </IifModule> but saw </IfModule>
2020-02-07T09:08:49+01:00 Synology [Fri Feb 07 09:08:49.110084 2020] [core:alert] [pid 32462:tid 140624099452672] [client 192.168.1.50:34388] /var/services/web/nextcloud/data/.htaccess: Expected </IifModule> but saw </IfModule>
2020-02-07T09:11:12+01:00 Synology [Fri Feb 07 09:11:12.579977 2020] [core:alert] [pid 32462:tid 140624208557824] [client 192.168.1.50:34394] /var/services/web/nextcloud/data/.htaccess: Expected </IifModule> but saw </IfModule>
2020-02-07T09:12:10+01:00 Synology [Fri Feb 07 09:12:10.283186 2020] [core:alert] [pid 32462:tid 140624183379712] [client 192.168.1.50:34399] /var/services/web/nextcloud/data/.htaccess: Expected </IifModule> but saw </IfModule>
2020-02-07T09:20:09+01:00 Synology [Fri Feb 07 09:20:09.222903 2020] [core:alert] [pid 32462:tid 140624057489152] [client 192.168.1.50:34437] /var/services/web/nextcloud/data/.htaccess: Expected </IifModule> but saw </IfModule>
2020-02-07T09:22:44+01:00 Synology [Fri Feb 07 09:22:44.829287 2020] [core:alert] [pid 32462:tid 140624074274560] [client 192.168.1.50:34459] /var/services/web/nextcloud/data/.htaccess: Expected </IifModule> but saw </IfModule>
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Were you able to solve this? I am stuck with SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused. I can successfully connect with usr/local/mariadb10/bin/mysql –u root –p and also using other users giving nexcloud database permissions.. but nothing. same error.

Comment: No sorry I gave up and am using Synology Drive for files and Moments for photos. Works great for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issues:

- phpMyAdmin worked with the user I created just for nexcloud (myuser)
- Command `usr/local/mariadb10/bin/mysql –u myuser –p` worked fine
- but still getting `QLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused` on the
  installation

Turned out, I had to tick the "Enable TCP/IP Connections" on MariaDB 10 packet. I also used 127.0.0.1:3307 for "database server"

https://blog.viking-studios.net/en/your-own-cloud-nextcloud-hub-installation-on-synology-diskstation-with-dsm-6-2/