# cannot configure NextCloud with MariadDB on Asustor NAS: Error while trying to create admin user

Tags: mariadb, nas, nextcloud

I'm trying to set-up the NextCloud-https app on an Asustor NAS following their doc https://www.asustor.com/en/online/College_topic?topic=273. This is using all Asustor apps.

I've set-up MariaDB (ticked the box "Enable MaridaDB remote access") and phpAdmin, created a user (MariaDB-php) with all privileges as per the tutorial. This shows fine in the phpAdmin console (visible at http://mynas/phpmyadmin/index.php?route=/server/privileges&viewing_mode=server). When I try then to set-up NextCloud using Database User MariaDB-php (and same database name and host mynas:3306), I get the error

```
cannot configure NextCloud with MariadDB on Asustor NAS: Error while trying to create admin user: Failed to connect to the database: An exception occurred in the driver: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'MariaDB-php'@'mynas' (using password: YES).
```

I hardly know anything at all about MariaDB etc, but I tried to dig a bit. I ssh'ed into the NAS as my admin-user and discovered that `mariadbd` is running as `root` (my admin-name is different). I can access essentially the same info as the console, e.g.

```
$ mysql -u root -p
Enter password: 
Welcome to the MariaDB monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MariaDB connection id is 104
Server version: 10.7.3-MariaDB Source distribution

Copyright (c) 2000, 2018, Oracle, MariaDB Corporation Ab and others.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

MariaDB [(none)]> SHOW GRANTS for 'MariaDB-php'@'%';
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Grants for MariaDB-php@%                                                                                                              |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO `MariaDB-php`@`%` IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '*SOMESTUFFHERE' WITH GRANT OPTION |
| GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `MariaDB-php`.* TO `MariaDB-php`@`%`                                                                          |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

However, when trying to use MariaDB directly as the user, this gives me the same error

```
$ mysql -u MariaDB-php -p
Enter password: 
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'MariaDB-php'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

Possibly this gives a clue, but I have no idea really. (At least, it's different from [Connection Refused Error installing Nextcloud on Synology NAS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60109826/connection-refused-error-installing-nextcloud-on-synology-nas)).

Final note, I found https://blog.viking-studios.net/en/your-own-cloud-nextcloud-hub-installation-on-synology-diskstation-with-dsm-6-2/ with lots of work-arounds for old Synology NAS which states

> you have to enter the root user of MariaDB and the password. Alternatively, every user who has the right to create databases can be used. The user is only used for installation. A separate user is created that Nextcloud uses for operation. The user you enter here, is stored nowhere.

I haven't tried to user `root` yet as it feels unsafe (but maybe not, as the tutorial grants the user all permissions anyway).